# Different results from function when I output ggplot graph or not, why?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, tidyverse

TLDR: function outputs different results based on whether it's plotting or not.

Basically I have a function that calculates some points based on some coefficients from a model (beta0;beta1).The function can either output a plot through `showPlot = TRUE` or not through `showPlot = FALSE`.

There is the initial function which is used in the secondary function, here it is:

```
library(tidyverse)

defun <- function(dm, b = c(beta0, beta1)){
  p <- 1 / (1 + exp(-(b[1] + b[2]*dm)))
  return(p)
}

beta0 <- 3.831 
beta1 <- -0.02253
```

Now come the weird part, this is the secondary function:

```
fun1<- function (vel = 1, delays = c(50,400), durbur = 5, distrec = 1000, dist = 2000, defun, outerLim = c(0, 0), simuln = 1000, showPlot = FALSE) 
{
  if (any(!is.function(defun))) 
    stop("Error: argument 'defun' must be a function...")
  if (any(is.na(distrec))) 
    distrec <- 0
  xLim <- c(0, sum(distrec) + sum(outerLim))
  recLoc <- c(outerLim[1], outerLim[1] + cumsum(distrec))
  yLim <- c(-dist, dist)
  transect <- floor((diff(yLim)/vel)/delays[1])
  del <- matrix(runif(transect * simuln, delays[1], delays[2]), 
                nrow = simuln, ncol = transect)
  del <- del + durbur
  trans <- t(apply(del, 1, cumsum))
  trans <- trans - matrix(runif(simuln, trans[, transect/2], trans[, (transect/2) + 1]), nrow = simuln, ncol    = transect)
  an.x <- matrix(runif(simuln, xLim[1], xLim[2]), nrow = simuln, ncol = transect)
  an.y <- matrix(trans * vel, nrow = simuln, ncol = transect)
  if (showPlot){
    
    # converting x coordinates to datframe
    xcor = pivot_longer(data = data.frame(an.x), everything()) %>%
      mutate(fish = as.numeric(sort(rep(sample(1:simuln),1,each = transect)))) %>% select(-name) %>% 
      rename(x = value,fish = fish)
    
    # converting y coordinates to dataframe
    ycor = pivot_longer(data = data.frame(an.y), everything()) %>% select(-name) %>% 
      rename(y = value)
    
    # binding x and y coordinates
    df3 = cbind(xcor,ycor)
    
    # mutate to factor for graphing purposes
    df3 = df3[,c("x","y","fish")] %>% mutate_at(vars(fish), ~ as.factor(.))
    
    print(ggplot() + xlim(0,xLim[2]) + 
            ylim(-dist, dist) + 
            geom_point(aes(x = recLoc, y = rep(0,length(recLoc))), colour = "red", size = 4) + 
            labs(x = "Horizontal spread",
                 y = "Vertical spread") + 
            geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y),data = df3) + 
            geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y,colour = fish),data = df3))
  }
  for (i in 1:length(recLoc)) {
    if (i == 1) {
      succ <- detP <- distM <- vector("list", length(recLoc))
      nDets <- matrix(NA, nrow = simuln, ncol = length(recLoc))
    }
    distM[[i]] <- sqrt((an.x - recLoc[i])^2 + (an.y)^2)
    detP[[i]] <- matrix(defun(distM[[i]]), nrow = simuln)
    succ[[i]] <- matrix(rbinom(length(detP[[i]]), 1, detP[[i]]), nrow = simuln)
    nDets[, i] <- rowSums(succ[[i]])
  }
  maxndet <- apply(nDets, 1, max)
  probsdet <- mean(maxndet > 1)
  return(data.frame(probsdet = probsdet))
}
```

```
set.seed(12331)

# with showPlot = FALSE
fun1(defun = defun, delays = c(50,400), vel = 1,simuln = 20,durbur = 5.0, distrec = rep(1000,10), dist = 1000, outerLim =   c(500,500), showPlot = FALSE)

# with showPlot = TRUE
fun1(defun = defun, delays = c(50,400), vel = 1,simuln = 20,durbur = 5.0, distrec = rep(1000,10), dist = 1000, outerLim =   c(500,500), showPlot = TRUE)
```

All seems to work ok, apart from the fact that when I run `showPlot = TRUE` I get different results (i.e. probsdet returned differs) from when I don't query a plot. I'm not sure what this is due to, whether it's a ggplot related issue/tidyverse or erroneous coding.

Can someone please explain why, and how to correct this behaviour?

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example.. Also it should be a minimal example.

Comment: The above should be reproducible. I can't shorten the function more than this otherwise it would be different.

Comment: Where is the code where you call the function `fun1`?

Comment: there is a `runif` in your code. You need to set `set.seed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function has randomness in it, so you shouldn't expect the results to be the same for two successive runs unless you use `set.seed`. *Note that you need to reset the seed every time you run the function.*

```
fun1(defun = defun)
#   probsdet
# 1    0.147

fun1(defun = defun)
#   probsdet
# 1    0.156


set.seed(47)
fun1(defun = defun)
#   probsdet
# 1    0.155
set.seed(47)
fun1(defun = defun)
#   probsdet
# 1    0.155
```

The code inside your `if(showPlot){}` clause also uses randomness (with the `sample()` function), so it effects the state of the random number generator. We can move the plotting code to the end of your function so all the non-plotting calculations are completed first, whether or not there is plotting.

```
fun1<- function (vel = 1, delays = c(50,400), durbur = 5, distrec = 1000, dist = 2000, defun, outerLim = c(0, 0), simuln = 1000, showPlot = FALSE) 
{
  if (any(!is.function(defun))) 
    stop("Error: argument 'defun' must be a function...")
  if (any(is.na(distrec))) 
    distrec <- 0
  xLim <- c(0, sum(distrec) + sum(outerLim))
  recLoc <- c(outerLim[1], outerLim[1] + cumsum(distrec))
  yLim <- c(-dist, dist)
  transect <- floor((diff(yLim)/vel)/delays[1])
  del <- matrix(runif(transect * simuln, delays[1], delays[2]), 
                nrow = simuln, ncol = transect)
  del <- del + durbur
  trans <- t(apply(del, 1, cumsum))
  trans <- trans - matrix(runif(simuln, trans[, transect/2], trans[, (transect/2) + 1]), nrow = simuln, ncol    = transect)
  an.x <- matrix(runif(simuln, xLim[1], xLim[2]), nrow = simuln, ncol = transect)
  an.y <- matrix(trans * vel, nrow = simuln, ncol = transect)

  for (i in 1:length(recLoc)) {
    if (i == 1) {
      succ <- detP <- distM <- vector("list", length(recLoc))
      nDets <- matrix(NA, nrow = simuln, ncol = length(recLoc))
    }
    distM[[i]] <- sqrt((an.x - recLoc[i])^2 + (an.y)^2)
    detP[[i]] <- matrix(defun(distM[[i]]), nrow = simuln)
    succ[[i]] <- matrix(rbinom(length(detP[[i]]), 1, detP[[i]]), nrow = simuln)
    nDets[, i] <- rowSums(succ[[i]])
  }
  maxndet <- apply(nDets, 1, max)
  probsdet <- mean(maxndet > 1)
  
  if (showPlot){
    
    # converting x coordinates to datframe
    xcor = pivot_longer(data = data.frame(an.x), everything()) %>%
      mutate(fish = as.numeric(sort(rep(sample(1:simuln),1,each = transect)))) %>% select(-name) %>% 
      rename(x = value,fish = fish)
    
    # converting y coordinates to dataframe
    ycor = pivot_longer(data = data.frame(an.y), everything()) %>% select(-name) %>% 
      rename(y = value)
    
    # binding x and y coordinates
    df3 = cbind(xcor,ycor)
    
    # mutate to factor for graphing purposes
    df3 = df3[,c("x","y","fish")] %>% mutate_at(vars(fish), ~ as.factor(.))
    
    print(ggplot() + xlim(0,xLim[2]) + 
            ylim(-dist, dist) + 
            geom_point(aes(x = recLoc, y = rep(0,length(recLoc))), colour = "red", size = 4) + 
            labs(x = "Horizontal spread",
                 y = "Vertical spread") + 
            geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y),data = df3) + 
            geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y,colour = fish),data = df3))
  }
  
  return(data.frame(probsdet = probsdet))
}
```

And, with that version of the function, we can reproduce the results:

```
set.seed(47)
fun1(defun = defun, showPlot = TRUE)
#   probsdet
# 1    0.155
```

Comment: I'll test this when I can. What I don't understand is that nothing is being saved from within the showplot call, so how can it influence the result of probsdet?

Comment: @Dasr when you generate a random number in R, the random number generator moves on to a new seed. Therefore when you draw a random number inside the "showPlot" conditional, the random seed is at a different value from when you don't go into that condition. That means you will draw different numbers for the `rbinom` call in the final chunk. This affects your output.

Comment: It's not about saving, it's about the RNG. Imagine the that you have a book of random numbers. `set.seed(47)` says start referencing random numbers beginning on page 47, and page 47 starts `5, 9, 2, 5, ...`, so those are the random numbers you'll use, in that order. Your version of the function uses some random numbers before the `showPlot` code, and some after. But `showPlot` also uses some random numbers too, so the random numbers used by the code after `showPlot` will be different if the `showPlot` code was run. My version of the function doesn't use any random numbers after `showPlot`.